# Add hook to default mode when using emacs -q -l

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

I have been loading emacs with `emacs -q -l "init.el"` quite a bit and was trying to enable auto-complete in my scratch buffer.  I was struggling to figure out why it wasn't working but realized it must have to do with the order of operations when emacs is loaded like this - a quick test with the following init file:

```
(package-initialize)
(require 'auto-complete)
(ac-config-default)
(add-hook 'lisp-interaction-mode-hook
      '(lambda ()
         (auto-complete-mode t)))
```

shows completion working as I would like when calling emacs as normal from the command line.  But if I call it as `emacs -q -l init.el` there is no dropdown completion.

Question: How can I get this hook to run?

I've tried variations on `after-init-hook` but none seem to work.

Comment: `lisp-interaction-mode` is initiated in the `*scratch*` in `startup.el` very early on in the startup process.  So, you would need to call the desired function(s) directly for the `*scratch*` buffer instead of relying on the `lisp-interaction-mode-hook` that has already run.  See line 1350 of `startup.el` (master branch):  https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/startup.el  You could test out that theory by evaluating `(funcall initial-major-mode)` in the scratch buffer, which would then call the hook and have the desired effect.

Comment: I see that the `after-init-hook` is actually run at line 1344 of the master branch `startup.el`, so something attached to that hook should logically be seen by code that runs at line 1350.  What version of Emacs are you running?

Comment: I'll need to run some tests on my own before being able to post an answer, and perhaps someone else will have it before I do.  I'm in the middle of another hobby project relating to Emacs at the moment . . . and am checking stackoverflow while Emacs is building . . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following analysis is based on `startup.el` of the master branch:  https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/startup.el

As I understand the question, it seeks an answer as to when the command line option `-l` aka `--load` FILE is run as compared to when the `*scratch*` buffer is initialized with the `initial-major-mode` that by default is `lisp-interaction-mode`.

Based on the sequence of events defined within `startup.el`, the `-l` or `--load` options are taken into consideration at line 2381 of the function `command-line-1`.

The function `command-line-1` runs at line 1366 of `startup.el`, which is subsequent to the `after-init-hook` at line 1344 and subsequent to the `*scratch*` buffer being initialized with the `initial-major-mode` at line 1350.

To the extent that the original poster would like to rely upon loading a file manually using the `-l` or `--load` option, then functions being assigned to the `lisp-interaction-mode-hook` will not be seen at line 1350 because they do not exist until `command-line-1` runs at line 1366.  One option the original poster may wish to consider would be the following:  `(with-current-buffer "*scratch*" (lisp-interaction-mode))` *after* the `auto-complete-mode` has been added to the `lisp-interaction-mode-hook`.

Comment: The `with-current-buffer` suggestion did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If starting Emacs from the command line, you could invoke the function to run near the end of the loading sequence, as follows:

```
emacs -f lisp-interaction-mode
```

See [Action Arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Action-Arguments.html#Action-Arguments) in the manual:

> ‘-f function’
>
> ‘--funcall=function’
>
> Call Lisp function function. If it is an interactive function (a command), it reads the arguments interactively just as if you had called the same function with a key sequence. Otherwise, it calls the function with no arguments.